# Python SDK Google Dataflow - name 'execfile' is not defined

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

Trying to install the DataflowPythonSDK  from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowPythonSDK

Followed directions but when trying to run the command,

```
python setup.py install
```

I get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "setup.py", line 89, in <module>
    _PYTHON_DATAFLOW_VERSION = get_dataflow_version()
    File "setup.py", line 60, in get_dataflow_version
    execfile(os.path.normpath('./google/cloud/dataflow/version.py'),
    NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
```

Any clues as to where this file should be found?  I am running in a virtual environment per the instructions and have cloned the SDK from GitHub

Comment: I think this may be a Python version issue.  If I am NOT in my virtual environment, my default Python version is Python 2.7.10.   However once I activate my virtual environment, then suddenly my default Python is Python 3.5.0.    So what should I do to rectify this?  BTW,  I installed virtual environment per the instructions on the git hub README,  My version is virtualenv 15.0.0.  So how do I change the virtualenv to have the Python 2.7 as default instead of 3.5?

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected the issue was with the Python version default when invoking

```
virtualenv /path/to/directory
```

I substituted this

```
sudo virtualenv --python=python2.7 /path/to/directory
```

and completed a successfull install and test of the package